# Laplacian in 4 spatial dimensions; 4th dimension warped

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, compactification, kaluza-klein

How can I prove the form of the Laplacian in four spatial dimensions, using the identification $y = y + 2\pi R$ for the fourth dimension and assuming the others as the usual Cartesian ones? I want to do this by letting the covariant Laplacian work on the 4-dimensional space, so my problem reduces to: what form should the 4-dim metric assume?